# Rails Fixtures Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I am getting an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `cards' for
>
> V1::CardsControllerTest:0x00000007c17238

when I am making the following call in an integration test:

```
card = cards(:one)
```

even though I have defined the fixture 'Cards'.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you including your fixtures in test_helper.rb?

Comment: What is a name of the fixture file? Is it 'Cards.yml', with capital first letter? It should be 'cards.yml'

Comment: @ArtemDorodovskyi thank you that was the problem. Thanks for your help!